# Report on my software not worked on windows 7 / 32 bit

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, report

I created a software on Windows 10 using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2015 in C#.

Now I want to install my software on Windows 7 / 32 bit; it is running, but my report is not working, I downloaded the reportviewer, but it's not working.

What should I do to a program that works correctly?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Any log or messgaes?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a lot of things , Binary incompatibility from development to client machine , lack of required windows updates , Incorrectly installed report run-time , lack of administrator privileges or missing Dlls . Try running it on  a 32 bit version of windows 10 if you haven't already.